# Повесить класс на соседний элемент. Коллекции

Tags: javascript, коллекции, css-selectors

Здравствуйте. Возможно ли как-нибудь повесить на соседний элемент класс посредством JS при клике, если эти селекторы в JS в виде коллекций?

Например, мне нужно при нажатии на `<span>` повесить класс на `<div>` под ним, вот примерный код:

```
<span class="caption">...</span>
<div class="wrapper">...</div>
<span class="caption">...</span>
<div class="wrapper">...</div>
..........
```

Написал JS:

```
var caption = document.querySelectorAll('.caption');
var wrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');

[].forEach.call(caption, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        [].forEach.call(wrapper, function(elem) {
            elem.classList.toggle('open');
        });
    });
});
```

Но при нажатии на `<span>` он добавляет класс всем `<div>`, что вовсе не то. Или придётся вешать класс на сам `<span>` и от него, посредством "+" в селектор, задавать стиль для `<div>`?

И ещё, если в `<div>` добавить ещё `<div>` для фона в виде стрелочки, который тоже будет коллекцией, до него можно будет добраться JS'ом? Типа:

```
<span class="caption">...</span>
<div class="wrapper">...
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не легко использовать jQuery с помощью метода .next() ?)

Будет типа: 
`
$(".caption").on("click", function(){
    $(this).next().addClass("wrapper");
});
`

Comment: ну или же чистый `js` и метод [`nextSibling`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Советую не заморачиваться чистым JS, и использовать JQuery. 
Вот примерно как будет выглядеть твой код

```js
// Отслаживаем нажатие кнопки на наш span
$(".caption").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $underSpan = $(this).next(); // Берет следующий тег после тега span, в нашем случае это div с классом wrapper
    $underSpan.toggleClass("clicked"); //Добавляет если нет класса, удаляет класс если он есть
    // $underSpan.addClass("clicked"); // Добавляет класс
    // $underSpan.removeClass("clicked"); // Удаляет класс
});
```

```css
.caption{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.clicked{
    color: red;
}
.wrapper{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="caption">Span 1</span>
<div class="wrapper">My Div 1</div>
<span class="caption">Span 2</span>
<div class="wrapper">My Div 2</div>
<span class="caption">Span 3</span>
<div class="wrapper">My Div 3</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать!

Comment: @Сергей Если вам ответ решил вашу проблему, можете нажать на галочку принять ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на чистом JS

```js
var caption = document.getElementsByClassName('caption');
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');

for (let i = 0; i < caption.length; i++) {
  caption[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < wrapper.length; i++) {
      wrapper[i].style.background = 'white'
    }
    wrapper[i].style.background = 'red'
  })
}
```

```css
.caption {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="caption">Span 1</span>
<div class="wrapper">My Div 1</div>
<span class="caption">Span 2</span>
<div class="wrapper">My Div 2</div>
<span class="caption">Span 3</span>
<div class="wrapper">My Div 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это довольно просто сделать на чистом JavaScript. Не думаю, что ради пары строчек стоит подгружать целую библиотеку.

Я предлагаю использовать метод `forEach` для прохода по всей коллекции и метод `nextElementSibling` для нахождения ближайшего сестринского элемента.

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.caption'); /* Собираем все спаны */

spans.forEach((e) => { /* Для каждого спана */
  const sibling = e.nextElementSibling; /* находим ближайший сестринский элемент */
  e.addEventListener('click', (el, e) => { /* назначаем спану обработчик события */
    sibling.classList.toggle('pink'); /* добавляем/убираем класс у сестринского элемента */
    const arrow = sibling.querySelector('.arrow'); /* добираемся до вложенного дива */
    if (arrow !== null) { /* проверяем есть ли вложенный див */
      arrow.classList.toggle('blue'); /* обрабатываем его класс */
    }  
  });
});
```

```css
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
.blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.caption {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="caption">Span 1</span>
<div class="wrapper">
  Div 1
  <div class="arrow">Arrow</div>
</div>
<span class="caption">Span 1</span>
<div class="wrapper">Div 1</div>
```